# Can't add elements from an attribute value to a set

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I have duplicate elements in one field (11223334) and would like them to bu unique in another (1234). I made a new field and am trying to use update cursor:

```
>>> with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("SD_Pattern_CLSCOM",["Day_Pattern","Day_Pattern2"]) as cursor:
...     for row in cursor:
...         a = set()
...         for i in row[0]:
...             a.add(i)
...         row[1] = a
...         cursor.updateRow(row)
```

...
And I am getting this error:

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
TypeError: value #1 - unsupported type:
```

Comment: What type of field is `Day_Pattern` and `Day_Pattern2`?  You are trying to store the set itself into the row, not the contents.  Do you need the values to stay in the same order?  I believe python sets do not retain value order, so you could end up with `set([4,2,1,3])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Midavalo mentioned, I'm going to assume both fields are text fields. You can eliminate some of your lines of code and replace it with something similar.

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("SD_Pattern_CLSCOM",["Day_Pattern","Day_Pattern2"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[1] = ''.join(set(row[0]))
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Of course, python sets don't necessarily retain the original sorting. So, a string of `'22113334'` might return `'1324'`.

You'll have to do a bit more processing to keep the original order, if necessary.

Comment: Thank you Fezter. I added sorted in front of set and got what I needed.

Comment: @ShaunO Please note that `sorted` will put the values in numeric order, not keep it in the original order, so Fezter's example of `22113334` would be returned as `1234` and not `2134`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to store a set like `set([1,2,3,4])` in your field, not a value `1234`.  Also I think sets don't retain value order, so could be `set([4,2,1,3])`.

Try this instead:

If fields are Text fields:

```
import itertools

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("SD_Pattern_CLSCOM",["Day_Pattern", "Day_Pattern2"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        x = ''.join(xx for xx, _ in itertools.groupby(row[0]))
        row[1] = x
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

If fields are Integer fields:

```
import itertools

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("SD_Pattern_CLSCOM",["Day_Pattern", "Day_Pattern2"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        x = int(''.join(xx for xx, _ in itertools.groupby(str(row[0]))))
        row[1] = x
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

[Hat-tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799050/5754917)

Note this won't remove additional instances of the same number, like in `1122331155` it will return `12315`.

Comment: My two cents here, if the order is important and the values should be unique, `x=[];[x.append(i) for i in str(row[0]) if i not in x]` will do.

Comment: Thank you Midavalo. I went with Fezter's answer because it was more in the realm of my understanding, not to say your solution isn't just as correct.